# Show percentage of presence of one variable given other variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I'm currently working on some plots, and I faced a problem that I could not solve right now based on my current ggplot2 knowledge.

I'm going to try and explain my problem using fictional data that I created in R. Below I leave the output of str command on my fictional dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ w: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ z: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
```

As you can see those are all dichotomous variables. Let's consider my dependent variable is y. The plot I want to do is a bar chart like this image below:

[image: Plot that I would like to make.]

I really wanted to make a plot like this one. And another one like this but also add a bar with prevalence of y comparing the group with 1 on independent variable (x, w and z) with the ones with 0 on independent variables (on x, w and z). So, in this second idea, it would be 6 bars instead of only 3. But any of the two ideas would work wonderfully for what I need to do. Thanks in advance for the community, you are always really helpful.

Example data:

```
d <- structure(list(x = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     w = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     z = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update - actually I misunderstood the question at first. [zx8754's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66994300/7941188) is wonderful, and my table approach (left below for posterity) is way to clunky.

Below a translation of zx8754's answer into tidyverse.

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- structure(list(x = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     w = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     z = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

d %>% 
  pivot_longer(-y, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(var, val) %>%
  summarise(perc = sum(y == 1)/ n())%>%
  ggplot(aes(var, perc)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(val)), position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'var'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I'd table first, and then use this for plotting your bars.

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- structure(list(x = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     w = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),     z = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

y <- d$y
tab_df <- data.frame(apply(d[c("x", "w", "z")], 2, function(x) {
  tab <- table(x[x != 0], y[x != 0])# first row will be y = 0
  tab / sum(tab) # for percentages
}))

tab_df %>% 
  mutate(y = 0:1) %>%
  pivot_longer(-y, names_to = "var", values_to = "percentage") %>%
  ggplot(aes(var, percentage)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(y))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great answers all round to this - was having fun doing it a while ago but good work to others for getting there faster :)

Answer (score 3):

Convert wide-to-long, then get summary when y is one per group:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# wide to long
setDT(d)
plotDat <- melt(d, id.vars = "y"
                )[ , .(yPC = sum(y == "1")/.N * 100),
                   by = .(variable, value)]

ggplot(plotDat, aes(variable, yPC, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was having a bit of fun doing the first one with `stat_summary` - looks like some great answers in already though, so just noting this one for interest.

(Edited to better correct the vertical placement of percentage text)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  pivot_longer(-y, names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, y = as.numeric(values))) +
  stat_summary(
    aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(y))),
    geom = "text",
    fun = ~  sum(.x == 1) / 15,
    vjust = -1
  ) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = ~ sum(.x == 1) / 15) +
  scale_y_continuous("Prevalence of 1s", labels = scales::percent, 
                     expand = expansion(add = c(NA, 0.05)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: ... .. why 1.03 ?

Comment: That's purely to put it *just a smidgen* above the top of the bar (without setting `vjust` to a negative number, which doesn't extend the top of the graph)

Comment: but those values... :D maybe better use nudge_y? (not tested, but should work)

Comment: ah sadly not, it doesn't seem to pass the nudge arguments to the text geom, though I'm not quite sure why. In manually adjusting, maybe adding 0.01 or so to the stat function would be more stable than multiplication of course.

Comment: ah I've of course just realised that it would alter the labels and not just the position :D. very silly. New solution needed!

Comment: also - I think it might not be entirely correct to just divide by 15... you're looking at percentage of "y" given x = 0, x = 1, w = 0, etc.

Comment: Good spot - I was clearly reading the question incorrectly!